# How to have more info on hovering a method on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, config

How can i have more information showing when i hover a method on VS Code (Like the picture)

[image: Sample image]

Usually you just get the information on the upper square of the box on the picture and i want to get the @param items too.

Comment: specify exactly what you want to see more, there is no `@param items`

Comment: what happens if you hold ctrl (cmd on MacOS) while hovering? Sometimes that results in more info being shown. Please also provide a code block for a [mre]- preferrably without having to download some huge dependency like angular.

Answer (score 1):

The [hover information](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#help-with-function-and-method-signatures) you see on symbols in VS Code comes from language-specific providers. Typically, there's support for common language-specific, tooling. For example, with JS/TS, typings for a particular method signature may come from a variety of sources including bundled declaration files, inline annotations, or even configurable, [automatic type acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_typings-and-automatic-type-acquisition). For additional information like parameter descriptions, VS Code will look for JSDoc annotations

> When type inference does not provide the desired information, type information may be provided explicitly with JSDoc annotations. This document describes the JSDoc annotations currently supported. [source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_typings-and-automatic-type-acquisition:%7E:text=When%20type%20inference%20does%20not%20provide%20the%20desired%20information%2C%20type%20information%20may%20be%20provided%20explicitly%20with%20JSDoc%20annotations.%20This%20document%20describes%20the%20JSDoc%20annotations%20currently%20supported.)

So to provide consumers of your code with parameter descriptions on hover in VS Code, you can add [JSDoc @param tags](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#param-and-returns) like so:

```js
/**
 * Build a skyscraper.
 * @param height How tall the skyscraper should be
 */
function buildSkyscraper(height: number) {
  ...
}
```

Then on hover, it looks like:
[image: screenshot of result in Visual Studio Code]